# My microphone makes noises

Tags: microphone

I have an issue  with my webcam :

[image]

I don't know why the bar section is full while I think it should not be, however sometimes when I shut down my PC and turn it on again I see that the problem is solved.
I also used https://mictests.com/ and noticed that the mic makes noises.

I really don't know what to do, any help is greatly appreciated.

Some other information:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post a recording of the noise from the mic?

Comment: @binaryOps20,I would like, but none of the mic test sites I know have the property to save the noise on my PC.

Comment: You can record the sound using a program like Audacity and then upload the file somewhere.

Comment: On Windows 10 you can use the Microsoft [voice recorder](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/how-to-use-voice-recorder-6fbb53d5-0539-abda-a9a4-0bcb84a778e7) app (you may have to install it from the MS Store, not sure). It will automatically record from your default microphone, and create an audio file.

Comment: Also, can you try with a different USB microphone / headset? Maybe your microphone is simply malfunctioning?

Comment: To add onto @sleske's suggestion, you might also want to try a different USB port, preferably on a different controller if possible

Answer (score 2):

There is not enough information to diagnose the problem, so I can only give a list of things you can try to narrow it down.

- First of all, try switching components. Can you try with a different microphone or headset? That way you can find out whether the problem is specific to the microphone you use - maybe your microphone is just broken. Ideally try with both an USB microphone and some other connection (analog input, Bluetooth), to rule out USB problems (though that seems less likely).
- Also try connecting your microphone to a different computer or phone. Does it make noise there, too? If yes, the microphone is most likely at fault.
- Try recording the noise. There are various recording apps available - you can use the [Microsoft Voice Recorder app](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/how-to-use-voice-recorder-6fbb53d5-0539-abda-a9a4-0bcb84a778e7) to create an audio file, or some other free software such as [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/). Upload it somewhere and link it in your question so people can try to diagnose the problem.
- Make sure that all Windows drivers are up-to-date. That may also help.

The above steps will hopefully help you narrow down the problem. With that information, you can then try more specific steps.

Answer (score 1):

Check your cables.

Induction is a real issue with audio cables. Move your cable so it doesn't pass near any other cables, specially power cords. (See [electromagnetic induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_induction) if you're interested why).

jack connectors may give problems after time. They get loose, or the cable soldering just get "bad". Move the connector to see if you feel something strange and look at the noise bar while doing it.

Have you tried another mic? If you don't have one, you can play around with your cable and see it that has an effect in the noise bar. If it does, this is probably a cable issue.

Windows has a recording utility from the box. Record the noise and listen to it. If it is merely white noise, it is some hardware or cable issue.

Sorry I can't be more specific, but problems like this without being able to see the device are hard to debug.

EDIT: I say windows declares it as a USB mic. As far as I know, noisy cables are less likely to happen than with old-fashioned jack audio, so it is hard to say.

Comment: I would think USB microphones would be less noisy usually, since the signal is digital and not analog.

Comment: @LayneBernardo yes, I noticed it and added as edit just after posted, noise is less likely, in fact, I've never seen noise similar to analog in usb cables, but i was not confident enough to say it would NEVER happen

Answer (score 1):

It's a digital device (USB microphone) so it's not likely to be a connectivity problem.  Click the properties button for that mic and go to the levels tab.  There are adjustments there that may allow you to eliminate the problem.  Some devices will have a "boost" option that can be disabled or you might just need to adjust the microphone volume sensitivity.  Failing that it sounds like it may be something internal to the mic itself or (not likely) drivers since a reboot fixes it.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes current also interferes with microphone,

1. try also taking out the charger while recording in case you are
   using a laptop

Answer (score 0):

I have the same full bars with my microphone, so I don't think that it
means much.
If I had to guess, I would say that they only mean that your microphone
is functioning correctly at 100%.

Your problem might be hardware, or a bad driver.

For suggesting a better driver, I need to know
the exact model of your microphone and what is its current driver.
You will find this information in the Device Manager,
right-click on the device and report its name and on the driver found in the
Driver tab.

For a hardware problem, a repair-shop might be able to help.

Comment: I've added some other information.

Comment: Also my mic model is XP-904M

Comment: I can't find anything by that name.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=XP-904M&rlz=1C1GCEA_enIR860IR860&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwidq9f1hN_tAhXiVRUIHbN5ArgQ_AUoAXoECAQQAw&biw=1517&bih=694

Comment: I can't read it, but I don't think this device has a driver, it probably uses the generic Windows driver. So I can't suggest a driver, leaving only hardware. Check your cable and if it passes near a powerful magnetic field. Try to isolate all you can, even if just by aluminium foil.